# PHP WSOD (white screen of death) on OS X Lion

Tags: php, macos, wsod

I'm getting a WSOD whenever I cause a parse error. I know there are plenty of similar questions, but I've tried all of those suggestions with no luck.
Running PHP 5.3.6 on Apache 2 on OS X Lion.

Here's the output of `php -i | grep error`:

```
display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
display_startup_errors => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => php_errors.log => php_errors.log
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 32767 => 32767
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
track_errors => Off => Off
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
```

The `32767` on error_reporting corresponds to `E_ALL | E_STRICT`.
When this happens, the error doesn't even show up in the logs. (Sometimes shows up in apache logs though).

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can't get an error printed out, comment out bigger and bigger chunks of code until the page renders properly (Safari should tell you you're getting an internal server error in Window->Activity). Then go backwards until you've commented out the smallest chunk that makes the page work. That's your problem code.

Comment: You pasted the output of php -i, but the values you really want are phpinfo() accessed through apache (cli has separate config).